# Can't take value of a macro (clojure)

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors

In this segment of clojure code:

```
(defn makeStructs ;line 27
 "open fName as a file and turns each line into a struct. Returns a Vector of structs"
 [fName]
   with-open[r (reader (file fName))]
   (let [r 
      res (doall (map makeStruct (line-seq r)))
      ]    
  (. r close)
     res
  ) 
)
```

I am getting this compiler error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/with-open (clojureHW.clj:27)
```

Line 27 is commented above.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @Svante: I apologize but the class I am taking expects me to learn one language a week and then write an extensive program in it. I have never used Lisp before and therefore am very poor at this. Prof has no office hours or I'd go there.

Comment: Whenever I try-something-new, I am unable to learn the basics without repeated application of the basics in a manner that looks like shotgun programming. I often mis-apply a learned basic or apply an inferred learning that is incorrect.  When I do this, it sometimes take a lot of time to resolve the issue, but I have then learned the basics.  I then usually try-something-new.

Comment: In C you can do `#define X 4` and on a subsequent line `bar = X;` to end up with the code `bar = 4;` but in Clojure you would do something more like `(defmacro X [] 4)` and somewhere else `(let [bar (X)])`.  So in the simplest cases there's a little extra work in Clojure, but in the hardest cases ... well, you simply can't do those things with the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to actually call the macro,

```
(defn makeStructs ;line 27
 "..."
 [fName]
   (with-open ; note the extra paren
```

Comment: It lisp the anwser is but parens around it :)

Answer (score 8):

```
(defn makeStructs ;line 27
 "open fName as a file and turns each line into a struct. Returns a Vector of structs"
 [fName]
   with-open[r (reader (file fName))]
   (let [r 
      res (doall (map makeStruct (line-seq r)))
      ]    
  (. r close)
     res
  ) 
)
```

This cant work because

1. You dont have parens around your `with-open`. This will be a normal symbol it its not called.
2. You again have a uneven number of forms in your let. You have r, res aund (doall ...). You already make the right binding for 'r' in with-open. All you need is

   (let [res (doall (map makeStruct (line-seq r)))] .... )
3. Why do you do `(. r close)` the with-open macro does that for you see here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-open

So you get:

```
(defn makeStructs 
 "open fName as a file and turns each line into a struct. Returns a Vector of structs"
 [fName]
   (with-open [r (reader (file fName))]
     (let [res (doall (map makeStruct (line-seq r)))]
        res)))
```

but since you only have one thing in let you dont really need that:

```
(defn makeStructs 
 "open fName as a file and turns each line into a struct. Returns a Vector of structs"
 [fName]
   (with-open [r (reader (file fName))]
     (doall (map makeStruct (line-seq r)))))
```

Lisp languages are really simple most programmers just want to make it hard for themselves because they're used to do it. A lot of the questions you have are because you've been used to things working like X, but now they work like Y. Try to not assume that things work like X and you will make your live easier.

Answer (score 1):

To add to your debugging tool bag when you see this error, I suggest you look for a function being defined or called without the open parenthesis '('.

In your particular case, as other answers have already noted, your code is missing the '(' at with-open.

```
(defn makeStructs ;line 27
 "open fName as a file and turns each line into a struct. 
  Returns a Vector of structs"
 [fName]
-->   with-open[r (reader (file fName))]
```

You were not calling with-open, but taking its value.

My mistake looked like the following:

```
--> defn ret-col-match
    "Returns true false match on sequence position w/ cmp-val."

    [row cmp-val col-idx]
    (if (= (nth row col-idx nil) cmp-val)
        true
        false))
```

You can see the missing '(' right before the defn.